# Azure Webjobs - Use INameResolver with TimerTrigger Function

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I've tried to configure a job with a simple function with a TimerTrigger.

```
public class Processor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Processor"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Processor()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process the Leads to Marketo.
    /// </summary>
    [Disable("Processor.Disable")]
    public async Task ProcessMessages([TimerTrigger("%Processor.TimerTrigger%")] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
    {


        // TODO : remove
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

My settings are defined in my app.config file:

```
<add key="Processor.TimerTrigger" value="00:01:00" />
<add key="Processor.Disable" value="false" />
```

When Starting my webjob, I've configure the job to use INameResolver and timertrigger:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Configure the job host
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration
    {
        NameResolver = new ConfigNameResolver() // Resolve name from the config file.
    };

    config.UseTimers();
    var host = new JobHost(config);
    // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously

    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

When executing the line `host.RunAndBlock()`, I've got this exception :

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException: Error indexing method 'ProcessMessages' ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.

I've put a break point in the class that implements the `INameResolver` interface but never hit.

Is there any way to configure a NameResolver with TimerTrigger ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TimerTrigger does not currently support `INameResolver`. Please open an issue in the public repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues) and we'll add that support. The other extension bindings support `INameResolver`. If it's important to you, we can get out a [pre-release build](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/%22Nightly%22-Builds) for you to use/verify ahead of the actual next release.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, Ive created a new issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/33. If you can get out a pre-release, I will be glad to test it.

Answer (score 4):

Confirmation that INameResolver is now supported in Timer Triggers using the technique in the original question and a resolver that looks like this:

```
public class ConfigNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(name);
    }
}
```